# Error occured in saved zip file+using Ionic.Zip

Tags: c#, zip

I have many files and I want to add thems in to a new zipfile.
I used this nameespace :
using Ionic.Zip

here my codes:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < deliveryList.Count; i++)
                    {
                       // System.IO.MemoryStream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream(x.Data.Data);
                        zip.AddEntry(x.StudentObj.Number.ToString() + '.' + t[t.Length -1 ],x.Data.Data);
}
 zip.Save(Response.OutputStream); //"Archive.zip");
```

now when I open the saved zip file,this error occured:

```
C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\D6IMASPE\TExamGrades.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet I see, I assume that zip is a Ionic.Zip.ZipFile instance, if not please provide more information.

ZipFile.Save(Stream) writes **to** the stream, and again *from what I can see from that snippet* it appears that you're trying to **write** to a Response stream, instead of **reading from** it.

Please provide more info and I will try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Zipping from the path instead from a stream.

```
    Dim zip = New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile()

    Try
        zip.AddFile(NameFile1,PathFile1)
        zip.AddFile(NameFile2,PathFile2)
        zip.AddFile(NameFile3,PathFile3)
        zip.Save(sZipDestinyPat)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ZipDirectory = -1
    End Try
```